# Bootstrap navbar dropdown is showing only when refresh the page in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In my angular application I have created the dashboard page with navigation links(home,about,report,profile)) using bootstrap.

For Report and profile links I have created the dropdown menu with hover effect using bootstrap .But the data of the hover effect is showing only when refresh  the page in angular.

**.component.html**

```
<li class="nav-item dropdown dmenu">
  <a routerLink="{{router.url}}" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="col" data-toggle="dropdown"><i class="fa fa-flag"></i> Report</a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu sm-menu" style="width: 340px;">
    <form name="forms">
      <label style="margin-left: 5px;">From date:</label><label style="margin-left: 97px;">To date:</label><br />
      <input type="date" style="width: 150px; margin-left: 5px;" id="name" required ngModel name="name" #name="ngModel" />&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="date" style="width: 150px;" id="date02" required ngModel name="date02" #date02="ngModel" />&nbsp;

      <select data-placeholder="Select..." multiple style="width: 150px; margin-left: 15px;">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option>Option 1</option>
        <option>Option 2</option>
        <option>Option 3</option>
        <option>Option 4</option>
        <option>Option 5</option>
        <option>Option 6</option>
        <option>Option 7</option>
        <option>Option 8</option>
      </select>
      <br />
      <br />
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-center" style="margin-left: 130px;">Show Report</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</li>
```

now I want to show the data with out refresh the page Can anyone help me regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it has something to do with the li element, try to put your dropdown in a separate div, like so:

```
<li class="nav-item">
  <div class="dropdown dmenu">
     <a routerLink="{{router.url}}" ... // rest of you code
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: I have tried even though it is not working it is working only when I refresh the page.But I don't want to refresh the page.